# Bash: How can I make a sync call until finding a match pattern in log file

Tags: bash

I have a start server script

```
startserver.sh
```

It will run as background task `startserver.sh &`
the script need to run for sometime until it can really run in running state.
The running state could write into log file `server.log` when it is ready.

So I need to know when the server is really run by executing a bash cmd. If not, I need to wait until the Running state is shown in the server.log.

Can i achieve this in bash?

Comment: Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
mkfifo my_fifo
tail -f server.log >my_fifo &
tail_pid=$!
perl -ne '/pattern/&&exit' <my_fifo
kill $tail_pid
rm my_fifo
```

EDIT : perl command can be replaced with

```
grep -l 'pattern' <my_fifo >/dev/null
```

or if grep support this option

```
grep -q 'pattern' <my_fifo
```